# Order of calls and side effects

Tags: c++, stream, operators, operator-precedence

Consider an operation like this :

```
int a = f1(mystream)*f2(mystream)+f3(mystream);
```

Where f1, f2, f3 are of the following form :

```
int f(std::istream&)
```

or

```
int f(std::ostream&)
```

Do I have the guarantee that `f1`, `f2` and `f3` will be executed in that order ?

Comment: No, they can be executed in any order.

Comment: I'm fairly sure it's compiler dependent, and g++/MS have it implemented in opposite directions of left/right and right/left.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The individual subexpressions are not sequenced with respect to one another. What is guaranteed is that any one function call completes before another starts, but the order of the three function calls is indeterminate.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the guarantee that every compiler use the order left-right. So if you are not sure you can look it up in your assembly-code. Once the compiler have created the assembly-code the order is guaranteed.
Have a look at the following Assembly-Code:

```
cout << f1() * f2() * f3();
00C6452E  call        f1 (0C61096h)  
00C64533  mov         esi,eax  
00C64535  call        f2 (0C6112Ch)  
00C6453A  imul        esi,eax  
00C6453D  call        f3 (0C61127h) 
00C64542  imul        esi,eax  
00C64545  mov         edi,esp
```

This is the code that my compiler creates ...

Answer (score 0):

No, they can be executed in any order.  This is because the built-in `*` and `+` operators do not introduce a [sequence point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point).  Some built-in operators, such as `||` and `&&` do introduce sequence points and causes the order of execution to be defined.

Comment: To be pedantic, it's only the *built-in* logical operators that define a sequence. Overloaded operators for user-defined types are just ordinary function calls.